# Remove Tomcat 7.0.33 and Install TomEE plus 1.5.1. The errors pop up

Tags: tomcat7, apache-tomee

I remove the Tomcat 7.0.33 and I install the TomEE plus 1.5.1. However, when I start TomEE server. The errors pop up. There are such errors on Tomcat.

Could you provide some suggestions? Thank you very much.

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
       at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
       at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:59)
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(ZipFile.java:529)
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$900(ZipFile.java:56)
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.nextElement(ZipFile.java:511)
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.nextElement(ZipFile.java:481)
       at java.util.jar.JarFile$1.nextElement(JarFile.java:242)
       at java.util.jar.JarFile$1.nextElement(JarFile.java:237)
       at org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.JarArchive$JarIterator.advance(JarArchive.java:105)
       at org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.JarArchive$JarIterator.advance(JarArchive.java:108)
       at org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.JarArchive$JarIterator.advance(JarArchive.java:108)
       at org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.JarArchive$JarIterator.advance(JarArchive.java:108)
       at org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.JarArchive$JarIterator.advance(JarArchive.java:108)
       at org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.JarArchive$JarIterator.advance(JarArchive.java:108)
       at org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.JarArchive$JarIterator.advance(JarArchive.java:108)
       at org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.JarArchive$JarIterator.advance(JarArchive.java:108)

....

Jan 04, 2013 10:07:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       ... 7 more

Jan 04, 2013 10:07:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       ... 11 more
```

Comment: What operating system and how did you install TomEE?

Comment: I am having the same trouble. Did you find a solution?